# Logging into Files in Documents External Storage in Android 11 (API 30) with de-and reinstalling the App

Tags: android, logging, logcat

I'm trying to put my log output in a file on Android 11. But I have a real struggle with it.
Before (Android 10 and below) I logged logcat and lockback and put both in Files on:

/storage/emulated/0/MyAppFolder/logs

Due to Android 11 restrictions this is not working anymore and I tried to use instead:

/storage/emulated/0/Documents/MyAppFolder/logs

But this is also only partial working.

For logcat I use the adb command line:

```
 val appDirectory = "${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()}/Documents/MyAppFolder/logs/mylog.log"
 val command = "logcat -f $appDirectory -r logFileSize*1024 *:debug"
 mLoggingProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
```

I also tried with

```
 val appDirectory = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "/MyAppFolder/logs/mylog.log"
 val command = "logcat -f " + logcatFile.absolutePath + " -r "+logFileSize*1024
 mLoggingProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
```

For locgat I use slf4j / Tonys Android-Logback lib : https://github.com/tony19/logback-android

using the same path in Documents as above.

All Folders in Documents are created so I see Documents/MyAppFolder/logs and also logback and logcat files are created. Also the App is than logging in the files.

My problem lies in the de- and reinstallation of the app.
If the app is de-installed than all the logs are kept in the folders ( which I want to). I can also reinstall the App but then there is no further logging. The new installed App can now not access the logs that were already created nor does it create new one in the same folder.

It seems that only the de-installed app has the rights to access the logs created.

I read myself a bit into the new file system but I have no clue how to solve the problem?

How can I create the logfiles for logcat and/or logback in the Documents Folder and after installing the App new it proceeds logging into files?
Or do I have to log into interal storage and then copy to external Documents everytime?

Thank for help

Comment: "It seems that only the de-installed app has the rights to access the logs created" -- correct. "it proceeds logging into files" -- use unique filenames. For example, your log filename could contain the day's date. Or, you could see if you get a unique `uid` for each app installation; if you do, then you could include that `uid` value in the filename. Or, add a sequence number to the filename, and test until you get a filename with a sequence number that works.

Comment: I think the better place for your log files would be `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<app packagename>/files`.

Comment: `seems that only the de-installed app has the rights to access the logs created.` Yes but your app can check if files exist. Use File.exists() and if you numbered them you can find the next free number if you make a loop.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestions. @Robert I could store it in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<app packagename>/files but this directory only belongs to the current installed app.

Comment: @blackapps yes, the files are numered. your suggestion works quit nice for logback as the highest number is the newest one. adb logcat instead names the files that newest is always number 0. so it cannot log after reinstall. I also triest to find a way using SAF, DocumentProvider, ContentProvider/Resolver to create a document that is accessable , but no luck so far. adb logcat -f only takes filepath no URI.

Comment: At reinstall you can use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user choose your Documents/MyAppFolder folder or Documents/MyAppFolder/loggs folder which gives you access to all existing files. You can then rename them a bit so the original file names are free again. Or put them in a subdir 'oldlogs;'. Or just rename loggs to oldloggs.